# Cannot apply cellValuePresenter/TypeConverter to XamDataGrid cells

Tags: c#, xaml, type-conversion, xamdatagrid

I also asked this [at Infragistics](http://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/p/76138/384534.aspx#384534), but don't know how to format my code there, so here it is properly formatted.

My goal is to present a table of structured data with the text of each cell using multiple colors. I have a typeconverter which will convert the data stored in a custom class to a label or textblock containing several text elements with different colors. The data is provided in a datatable (any method that works will be fine) and each value is correctly applied to a cell.

The problem is that instead of using my TypeConverter it uses the ToString method, which I override  so I know the model correct model data is mapped on the grid cell by cell. Also the ControlTemplate properties that I'm using are not applied, which tells me the ControlTemplate is not being used.

A concern is it may not be possible to have text where different letters have different colors in a datagrid. If so, is there another way that can be done while still having a good user experience and keeping the design in the xaml file (which is hard with a grid).

As I understand it my code should define a custom CellValuePresenter, can anyone please help me to apply it?

I'm posting my relevant code here. Most of it is obfuscated so please don't focus on spelling errors.

```
  <Window x:Class="ViewName"
          xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
          xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
          xmlns:local="clr-namespace:LocalNamespace"
          xmlns:ViewModel="clr-namespace:LocalNamespace.ViewModel"
          xmlns:model="clr-namespace:LocalNamespace.Model"
          xmlns:igDP="http://infragistics.com/DataPresenter"
          >
      <Window.Resources>
          <local:Converter x:Key="converter" />
          <ViewModel:ViewModelLocator x:Key="viewModelLocator" />
          <Style TargetType="{x:Type igDP:CellValuePresenter}" x:Key="cellTemplate" x:Name="cellTemplate" >
              <Setter Property="Template">
                  <Setter.Value>
                      <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type igDP:CellValuePresenter}">
                          <Label 
                              Content="{Binding Converter={StaticResource converter}}"
                              Width="200"
                              MaxWidth="600"
                              MinHeight="20"
                              />
                      </ControlTemplate>
                  </Setter.Value>
              </Setter>
          </Style>
      </Window.Resources>
        <StackPanel Name="stackPanel">
            <igDP:XamDataGrid Name="DifferenceGrid" DataSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource viewModelLocator}, Path=ViewModel.Model}" 
                              ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
                <igDP:XamDataGrid.FieldLayouts>
                    <igDP:FieldLayout>
                        <igDP:FieldLayout.Fields>
                            <igDP:Field>
                                <igDP:Field.Settings>
                                    <igDP:FieldSettings 
                                        CellValuePresenterStyle="{StaticResource cellTemplate}">
                                    </igDP:FieldSettings>
                                </igDP:Field.Settings>
                            </igDP:Field>
                        </igDP:FieldLayout.Fields>
                    </igDP:FieldLayout>
                </igDP:XamDataGrid.FieldLayouts>
            </igDP:XamDataGrid>
        </StackPanel>
  </Window>

    class ViewModelLocator
    {
        private static ViewModel viewModel = new ViewModel();

        public ViewModel ViewModel
        {
            get
            {
                return viewModel;
            }
        }
    }

  public class ViewModel
    {
        private DataTable model;

        public DataTable Model
        {
            get
            {
                return this.model;
            }

            private set
            {
                this.model = value;
            }
        }

    [global::System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter(typeof(Model.CustomClass))]
    public class Converter : TypeConverter, IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (this.CanConvertTo(targetType))
            {
                return this.ConvertTo(value);
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (this.CanConvertFrom(targetType))
            {
                return this.ConvertFrom(value);
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }

        public new bool CanConvertFrom(Type sourceType)
        {
            // Textboxes don't need to be converted back.
            return sourceType == typeof(Model.CustomClass);
        }

        public new bool CanConvertTo(Type destinationType)
        {
            return destinationType == typeof(Model.CustomClass);
        }

        public object ConvertTo(object value)
        {
            return this.ConvertCustomClassToTextBlock(value);
        }

        public new object ConvertFrom(object value)
        {
            return this.ConvertCustomClassToTextBlock(value);
        }

        private object ConvertCustomClassToTextBlock(object value)
        {
            TextBlock text = new TextBlock();
            Label cell = new Label();

      // Construct the TextBlock.

      cell.Context = text;
      return text; // Or cell, whatever works.
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

XamDataGrid cells contain editors and for values that should be presented as text, editor is XamTextEditor.

You must modify template of XamTextEditor and provide your own like in the following code:

```
<Window x:Class="XamDataGridApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:igDP="http://infragistics.com/DataPresenter"
        xmlns:igEditors="http://infragistics.com/Editors"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:XamDataGridApp"
        Title="Colorful XamDataGrid" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">
    <igDP:XamDataGrid FieldLayoutInitialized="OnFieldLayoutInitialized">
        <igDP:XamDataGrid.DataSource>
            <!-- Replace this with your data source. -->
            <local:DataSourceMock/>
        </igDP:XamDataGrid.DataSource>
        <igDP:XamDataGrid.Resources>
            <local:XamTextEditorConverter x:Key="XamTextEditorConverter" x:Shared="True"/>
            <Style TargetType="igEditors:XamTextEditor" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type igEditors:XamTextEditor}}">
                <Style.Setters>
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type igEditors:XamTextEditor}">
                                <Border x:Name="MainBorder" 
                                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                        SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}">
                                    <ContentPresenter
                                        Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                        HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                        VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
                                        <ContentPresenter.Content>
                                            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource XamTextEditorConverter}">
                                                <Binding Path="DisplayText" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"/>
                                                <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"/>
                                            </MultiBinding>
                                        </ContentPresenter.Content>
                                    </ContentPresenter>
                                </Border>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style.Setters>
            </Style>
            <Style TargetType="igEditors:XamTextEditor" x:Key="CustomClassXamTextEditorStyle" x:Shared="True" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type igEditors:XamTextEditor}}">
                <Setter Property="ValueToDisplayTextConverter" Value="{x:Static local:CustomClassToStringConverter.Instance}"/>
                <Setter Property="ValueToTextConverter" Value="{x:Static local:CustomClassToStringConverter.Instance}"/>
            </Style>
        </igDP:XamDataGrid.Resources>
    </igDP:XamDataGrid>
</Window>
```

Following IMultiValueConverter is used to generate XamTextEditor content imperatively:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Media;
using Infragistics.Windows.DataPresenter;
using Infragistics.Windows.Editors;

namespace XamDataGridApp
{
    class XamTextEditorConverter : IMultiValueConverter
    {
        private static readonly IList<Brush> colors = new Brush[] { Brushes.Red, Brushes.Green, Brushes.Blue };

        public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            var displayText = (string)values[0] ?? string.Empty;

            // Context that can be used for custom coloring.
            var editor = (XamTextEditor)values[1];
            var dataItemPresenter = editor.Host as DataItemPresenter;

            // Context that can be used for custom coloring.
            var dataValue = editor.Value;
            var dataItem = dataItemPresenter != null ? dataItemPresenter.Record.DataItem : null;

            var textBlock = new TextBlock()
            {
                TextWrapping = editor.TextWrapping,
                TextAlignment = editor.TextAlignment
            };

            for (int i = 0; i < displayText.Length; ++i)
                textBlock.Inlines.Add(new Run(displayText[i].ToString()) { Foreground = colors[i % colors.Count] });

            return textBlock;
        }

        public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }
    }
}
```

ContentPresenter inside XamTextEditor template must be data-bound to editor's DisplayText property because XamDataGrid cells are virtualized and with the binding we instruct XamDataGrid to regenerate ContentPresenter content when cell virtualization kicks in (when CellValuePresenter gets reused to present another value). Also, because of the data-binding, content will be regenerated even if it is changed outside of XamDataGrid.

MultiBinding is used to pass a context (XamTextEditor) from which data value and data item can be extracted and used in a coloring logic. If context is not required, simple binding to DisplayText with IValueConverter can be used instead.

---

**UPDATE:**

In order for your converter to be used by XamDataGrid, you must define CellValuePresenterStyle in FieldSettings (not FieldLayouts) like in the following XAML snippet:

```
<igDP:XamDataGrid Name="DifferenceGrid" DataSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource viewModelLocator}, Path=ViewModel.Model}" 
                      ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
    <igDP:XamDataGrid.FieldSettings>
        <igDP:FieldSettings CellValuePresenterStyle="{StaticResource cellTemplate}"/>
    </igDP:XamDataGrid.FieldSettings>
</igDP:XamDataGrid>
```

With this code snippet, you specify default CellValuePresenterStyle for all cells in a XamDataGrid.

If you want to specify that your CustomClass column uses XamTextEditor and that all other columns use their own default editor, you can do it by handling [FieldLayoutInitialized](http://help.infragistics.com/Help/NetAdvantage/WPF/2011.2/CLR4.0/html/InfragisticsWPF4.DataPresenter.v11.2~Infragistics.Windows.DataPresenter.DataPresenterBase~FieldLayoutInitialized_EV.html) event like in the following code:

```
private void OnFieldLayoutInitialized(object sender, FieldLayoutInitializedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var field in e.FieldLayout.Fields)
        if (field.DataType == typeof(Model.CustomClass))
        {
            field.Settings.EditorType = typeof(XamTextEditor);
            // Set Editor style in which display converter and edit converter are specified.
            field.Settings.EditorStyle = (Style)((FrameworkElement)sender).FindResource("CustomClassXamTextEditorStyle");
        }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml from above is updated to reflect these changes.

Here is also code for CustomClassToStringConverter which I used to convert CustomClass to string and back again when displaying and editing CustomClass in XamDataGrid (I added Text property to CustomClass since I didn't know how you extract text from it):

```
class CustomClassToStringConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public static CustomClassToStringConverter Instance = new CustomClassToStringConverter();

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return ((CustomClass)value).Text;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return new CustomClass() { Text = (string)value };
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, atleast this shows the principle is possible. I got your example working, so now I'm trying to implement it in my window. In my window the XamTextEditor is not applied, pretty much the same problem as the other template not being applied.

Comment: Can't get it to call my typeconverter at all.

Comment: The XamTextEditorConverter is getting called but it get's the values of an entire row in a DataPresenter.DataRecord and the targettype is Object instead of TextBox. Also the CustomClassToStringConverter has to return a TextBox, would that work? It's not getting called now, also the OnFieldLayoutInitialized is not getting called. I assumed it should be inside the ViewName class so I put the OnFieldLayoutInitialized in ViewName.xaml.cs

Comment: You can get property value from dataValue local variable inside XamTextEditorConverter. Target type is Object because binding is set on ContentPresenter.Content property which is of type Object. It would not work if CustomClassToStringConverter would return TextBox because this converter is used in XamTextEditor to convert CustomClass to string and back (you need to implement ConvertBack only if column is editable) (it must be string because this value will be set to XamTextEditor.DisplayText property which is of type string).

Comment: OnFieldLayoutInitialized is not getting called - please check your XamDataGrid XAML if you set event handler like this 
<igDP:XamDataGrid FieldLayoutInitialized="OnFieldLayoutInitialized"> And make sure that field layouts are autogenerated (remove <igDP:XamDataGrid.FieldLayouts>...</igDP:XamDataGrid.FieldLayouts> from your initial code).

Comment: Thanks stupid that I din't see that. Then I cannot use XamTextEditor.DisplayText because I need the result type to be TextBox. So instead I'm using Value, which is an object. But now the contents of each cell is its description: "DataRecord- {row number} Natural Key:"

Comment: Why do you need the result to be TextBox? You can also edit textual data with XamTextEditor and XamTextEditor plays naturally with XamDataGrid (like edit events, edit shortcuts, undo edits, etc..).

Comment: It needs to be multiple colors per cell. No edits, just a very good data display. Maybe XamGrid is better, but MVVM is a requirement.

Comment: If edit is not required, then you should use TextBlock, not TextBox. XamTextEditorConverter from my code is doing exactly that - it generates TextBlock with multi-color text. I just used three colors to color each letter differently, but you can make your own logic, you have all the data needed in variables dataValue and dataItem.

Comment: Of course TextBlock, I get confused between TextBlock and TextBox.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks I got it working now. Had to provide a seperate datasource with textblocks, don't need the multibinding now. But I don't know if the MVVM thing still applies, it's a pretty ugly solution.

```
    public DataTable TextBlocks
    {
        get
        {
            Converter converter = new DifferenceToTextConverter();
            DataTable table = new DataTable();

            foreach (DataColumn col in this.Model.Columns)
                table.Columns.Add(col.ColumnName, typeof(TextBlock));

            foreach (DataRow row in this.Model.Rows)
            {
                DataRow addedRow = table.NewRow();
                for (int col = 0; col < row.ItemArray.Length; col++)
                {
                    addedRow[col] = converter.ConvertTo(row[col]);
                }

                table.Rows.Add(addedRow);
            }

            return table;
        }
    }
```