# programmatically add child to xamdatatree node

Tags: c#, wpf

The code `visualNode.Nodes.Add` gives a *NullReferenceException* because at that point Nodes is not initiated.

```
private XamDataTreeNode LoadTree(XmlNode dataNode, int index)
{
    XamDataTreeNode visualNode = new XamDataTreeNode(index, null, MakeTextBox(dataNode.Name), false, null);

    foreach (XmlNode child in dataNode.ChildNodes)
    {
        visualNode.Nodes.Add(LoadTree(child, VisualChildrenCount));
    }

    visualNode.IsExpanded = true;

    return visualNode;  
}
```

I've tried using `ItemsSource` but the `XamDataTreeNode.ItemsSource` is protected.

So how to Fill the `XamDataTree` with values?

I was able to do this with the WPF tree control but not with the Infragistics tree control.

Edit, I will clarify some more:

@HighCore: The UIelements that I want to use and how they look can only be determined after analysis of the data.

@D J: How would you databind when the data structure can be any xml structure?

Comment: Do not manipulate UI elements in code. UI is not data.

Comment: The data source I need to use depends on the position in the tree. Also I need to analyze the data and manipulate the looks of a tree node based on the data in it's childs and some other stuff. Also I tried using visualNode.ItemsSource to set datasource but it's protected. Note I wanted something similar with a xamdatagrid and never got the converter to work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13747485/cannot-apply-cellvaluepresenter-typeconverter-to-xamdatagrid-cells

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by mapping the XamDataTree to a tree structure where a Label is provided that is used as content. With a standard [PropertyChangedNotifier](http://www.e-pedro.com/2009/04/creating-a-custom-observable-collection-in-wpf/)

```
public class TreeNode : PropertyChangedNotifier
{
  private Label text;
  private System.Drawing.Image icon;
  private ObservableCollection<TreeNode> children;
}

        <ig:XamDataTree.GlobalNodeLayouts>
            <ig:NodeLayout
                Key="Children"
                DisplayMemberPath="Text"
                TargetTypeName="Model.TreeNode" 
                >
            </ig:NodeLayout>
        </ig:XamDataTree.GlobalNodeLayouts>
```